# how to separate nolhmann json object's into strings

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to take my json obect which stores the data from a .json file and turn the data into strings. I am working with the nolhmann json dictionary.

Here is the .json file:

```
"dictionary": [
   {"word": "MEAGRE", "definition": "A large European scinoid fish (Scina umbra or S. aquila),having white bloodless flesh. It is valued as a food fish. [Writtenalso maigre.]"},
    {"word": "GRUGRU WORM", "definition": "The larva or grub of a large South American beetle (Calandrapalmarum), which lives in the pith of palm trees and sugar cane. Itis eaten by the natives, and esteemed a delicacy."}
```

Here is my code for the file

```
    string filename = line.substr(input.size()+1, line.size());
    filename[11] = toupper(filename[11]);
    cout << filename << "\n";


    ifstream i(filename);
    if (i.is_open()) {
        cout << "it is open\n";
        json j;
        i >> j;
        for (json::iterator it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << "\n";
            //how to seperate into strings??
        }

    }
```

This is  my first time working with json files, so I am still tryng to understand them.
So is there a way to store the information seperately, so I could have a

string = the information in word

string = the information in definition

because all of the different json dictionaries have different implementations, I am finding it very difficult to figure this out.

Comment: Don't try to parse JSON yourself. Find a library (which you should not ask about here, it's off-topic) and use that instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is nlohmann the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - Here's a working example based on your actual file JSON. NOTE - your JSON as posted is not valid, so had to fix it up first. I skipped the actual file reading part, and just jumped straight into it as if the file was already read into a string denoted by the static const variable '**json_data_from_file**'. If you need help in reading the file into an std::string let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "json.h"

static const std::string json_data_from_file = R"({
"dictionary": [{
               "word": "MEAGRE",
               "definition": "A large European scinoid fish (Scina umbra or S. aquila),having white bloodless flesh. It is valued as a food fish. [Writtenalso maigre.]"
               },
               {
               "word": "GRUGRU WORM",
               "definition": "The larva or grub of a large South American beetle (Calandrapalmarum), which lives in the pith of palm trees and sugar cane. Itis eaten by the natives, and esteemed a delicacy."
               }
               ]
})";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "json data:\n" << json_data_from_file << "\n";

    try
    {
        // Now attempt to convert file data to json
        json jdict = json::parse(json_data_from_file);
        json j = json::parse(jdict["dictionary"].dump());
        for (const auto& i : j) {
            json jsonobj( i );
            std::string word = jsonobj["word"].dump();
            std::cout << "word: " << word << "\n";
            std::string definition = jsonobj["definition"].dump();
            std::cout << "definition: " << definition << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        //...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is ss.str() ?

Comment: The file data is already in json format, I'm trying to seperate the data into strings of words and definitions.

Comment: ss.str() gets you the std::string from the string stream. Yes, the file data is expected to be in json format otherwise you may get an exception. To clarify, ss (string stream) holds the file data (bytes). That gets passed to the json::parse() to convert to a json object. Then you can use as a dictionary.

Comment: @upsidedownturtle see me edited answer - changed things to match your json. let me know.

Comment: Thanks for showing this to me step by step! Sorry about the .json file it has about 40 word-definitions so I didn't want to post the whole thing. I still have a lot to learn about these things, but I feel as if I am headed into the right direction now! Thanks again @kvr